# how to export datatable javaScript data to eccel, without exporting hidden columns, but not affecting hidden responsive data?

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable, through a form of checks I show and or hidden columns, besides having the active responseive feature; which makes some data hidden with the + drop-down in the first colunma. The ploblem is that when exporting the datatable, it exports all the data, even the hidden ones. if i add
 exportOptions: {columns: ': visible'}} in the configuration of the export button only exports the visible data of the table, it does not export the data hidden by the responsive, as I can export all the active data of the datatable, that is to say that are visible and hidden only by the responsive?

the implementation is with datatables and jquery

```
/*With this function I create the table*/
function reloadtable(datos, tabla, alertIS, jqform) {
    tablaret = $('#' + tabla).DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: datos,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        responsive: true,

        columnDefs: [

            {
                "title": "Ejecución",
                "targets": 0,
                "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {}
            },
            {
                "title": "Estado",
                "targets": 1,
                "createdCell": function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    if (alertIS == true) {
                        let background = "";
                        let paso;
                        if (cellData == "Finalizado" || cellData == "Cancelada" || cellData == "En Proceso") {
                            switch (cellData) {
                                case "Finalizado":
                                    background = '#004DFF';
                                    break;
                                case "Cancelada":
                                    background = '#BABABA';
                                    break;
                                case "En Proceso":
                                    background = '#FFAA00';
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    background = '#FFFFFF';
                                    break;
                            }

                        } else {
                            console.log(rowData["ejecucion"]);
                            console.log();

                            background = evalfechaByColor(rowData["ejecucion"], rowData["TareaRangoFin"]);
                            if (background != "#000000" && cellData == "Sin Asignar") {
                                background = "#0008FF"
                            }
                        }
                        let color = background == "#000000" ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                        $(td).css('border', 'solid 5px #FFFFFF');
                        $(td).css('border-radius', '1rem');
                        $(td).css('color', color);
                        $(td).css('background', background);
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "Cod tarea",
                "targets": 2,
            }, {
                "title": "Usuario de campo",
                "targets": 3,
            },
            {
                "title": "Prioridad",
                "targets": 4,
            },
            {
                "title": "Cliente",
                "targets": 5,
            },

            {
                "title": "Doc cliente",
                "targets": 6,
            },
            {
                "title": "Dirección",
                "targets": 7,
            },
            {
                "title": "Teléfono 1",
                "targets": 8,
            },
            {
                "title": "Teléfono 2",
                "targets": 9,
            },
            {
                "title": "Sede",
                "targets": 10,
            },
            {
                "title": "Campaña",
                "targets": 11,
            },
            {
                "title": "Zona",
                "targets": 12,
            },
            {
                "title": "Ajendamientos",
                "targets": 13,
            },
            {
                "title": "Tipo tarea",
                "targets": 14,
            },
            {
                "title": "Tipo de servicio",
                "targets": 15,
            },
            {
                "title": "Novedad",
                "targets": 16,
            }, {
                "title": "Tipo vehoculo",
                "targets": 17,
            },
            {
                "title": "Peso",
                "targets": 18,
            },
            {
                "title": "Cantidad",
                "targets": 19,
            },
            {
                "title": "Volumen",
                "targets": 20,
            },
            {
                "title": "Creación",
                "targets": 21,
            },
            {
                "title": "Inicio recorrido",
                "targets": 22,
            },
            {
                "title": "Fin recorrido",
                "targets": 23,
            },
            {
                "title": "Inicio de tarea",
                "targets": 24,
            },
            {
                "title": "fion de tarea",
                "targets": 25,
            },
            {
                "title": "Inicio de rango",
                "targets": 26,
            },
            {
                "title": "Fin de rango",
                "targets": 27,
            },
            {
                "title": "Tim Est de tarea",
                "targets": 28,
            },
            {
                "title": "Tiempo de tarea",
                "targets": 29,
            },
            {
                "title": "Tim Est Recorrido",
                "targets": 30,
            },
            {
                "title": "Tiempo recorrido",
                "targets": 31,
            },
            {
                "title": "Orden",
                "targets": 32,
            },
            {
                "title": "calificaíon",
                "targets": 33,
            },
            {
                "title": "Comentarios calificacíon",
                "targets": 34,
            },
            {
                "title": "notas",
                "targets": 35,
            },
            {
                "title": "Opciones",
                "targets": 36,
            }
        ],
        columns: [{
                data: "ejecucion"
            },
            {
                data: 'estado'
            },
            {
                data: 'codetarea'
            },
            {
                data: 'nameDriver'
            },
            {
                data: 'prioridad'
            },
            {
                data: 'nomClient'
            },
            {
                data: 'identiClient'
            },
            {
                data: 'direction'
            },
            {
                data: 'tel1'
            },
            {
                data: 'tel2'
            },
            {
                data: 'sede'
            },
            {
                data: 'campaña'
            },
            {
                data: 'zona'
            },
            {
                data: 'ajendamientos'
            },
            {
                data: 'tipoTarea'
            },
            {
                data: 'typeService'
            },
            {
                data: 'prsNoved'
            },
            {
                data: 'tipvehi'
            },
            {
                data: 'peso'
            },
            {
                data: 'piezaCant'
            },
            {
                data: 'volumen'
            },
            {
                data: 'creation'
            },
            {
                data: 'RecHoraIn'
            },
            {
                data: 'RecHoraFin'
            },
            {
                data: 'TareaHoraIn'
            },
            {
                data: 'TareaHoraFin'
            },
            {
                data: 'TareaRangoIn'
            },
            {
                data: 'TareaRangoFin'
            },
            {
                data: 'TareaTiempoEst'
            },
            {
                data: 'TareaTiempoReal'
            },
            {
                data: 'RecTiempoEst'
            },
            {
                data: 'RecTiempoReal'
            },
            {
                data: 'idRel'
            },
            {
                data: 'rate'
            },
            {
                data: 'rateObs'
            },
            {
                data: 'notas'
            },
            {
                "mData": null,
                "bSortable": false,
                "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                    let obsi = "";
                    if (alertIS == true) {
                        obsi = `
                    <button id='delet' class='btn btn-info mx-1' onclick='info("` + full['key'] + `")'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button>
                    <button id='infocierre' class='btn btn-success mx-1' onclick='ifoClose("` + full['key'] + `")'><i class='fas fa-clipboard-check'></i></button>
                    `
                    }
                    return obsi;;
                }
            }

        ],

        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]
        ],
        "language": configLanguafetable,
        dom: "<'d-block d-md-flex justify-content-md-around'<'my-2'l><B><f>>" + "rtip",
        buttons: [{
                extend: 'copy',
                text: "Copiar",
                exportOptions: {
                    // columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    //columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                exportOptions: {
                    // columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                exportOptions: {
                    // columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {
                    // columns: ':visible'
                }
            },

        ],


    });


    return tablaret;
}
//With this function I create the form
function CreaCtlVosibletable(form) {
    let DataTar = ["Todos",
        "Ejecución", "Estado", "Cod tarea", "Usuario de campo", "Prioridad", "Cliente", "Doc cliente", "Dirección", "Teléfono 1", "Teléfono 2", "Sede", "Campaña", "Zona", "Ajendamientos", "Tipo tarea", "Tipo de servicio", "Novedad", "Tipo vehoculo", "Peso", "Cantidad", "Volumen", "Creación", "Inicio recorrido", "Fin recorrido", "Inicio de tarea", "fion de tarea", "Inicio de rango", "Fin de rango", "Tim Est de tarea", "Tiempo de tarea", "Tim Est Recorrido", "Tiempo recorrido", "Orden", "calificaíon", "Comentarios calificacíon",
        "Obciones"
    ]
    DataTar.forEach((element1, index) => {
        activo = index < 7 && index > 0 ? "checked" : ""
        let itemName = element1.replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase()).replace(/ /gi, "")


        if (index < (DataTar.length)) {
            $("#" + form).append(`
            <div class="btn-group" >
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="` + itemName + `" id="` + itemName + `" ` + activo + ` autocomplete="off">
                    ` + element1 + `
                </label>
            </div>
       `);
        }
    })
}
//with this hidden function and I show columns
function chageVicibleTable(tabla, jqform) {
    $("#" + jqform + " input").each(function(index, element) {
        if (element.id != "Todos" && index != element.id != "Opciones") {
            let active = $("#" + this.id).prop('checked') == true || $("#Todos").prop('checked') == true ? true : false;
            tabla.columns(index - 1).visible(active);
        }
enter code here
    })

    tabla.columns.adjust().draw();

}
```